# React never ending loop in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Apologies.
React noob here.

Got an issue where my code has stuck on a never ending loop.
I've stripped the code down only to the part I believe that's causing the problem.

```
function Packages(){

    const [packages, setPackages] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!packages){
            getPackages();
        }
    });

    const getPackages = async () => {
        const resp1 = await instance.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
        setPackages(resp1);
    };
}
```

I've used the `useEffect` method to match the componentDidMount. Is that correct?

The moment I comment "setPackages(resp1);" the never ending loop stops.
I probably am using the useEffect and useState hooks wrong.

Appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: Add an empty dependency array to `useEffect` so it only executes once on the component's first render: `useEffect(() => ..., []);`

Comment: Since you're only running the effect once you won't need that condition there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't pass a second argument to the `useEffect` hook, it will execute every time your component re-renders.

If you want to fetch the data only once after the component has mounted, then pass an empty dependency array to the `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(!packages){
       getPackages();
   }
}, []);
```

Doing this will fix the infinite execution of `useEffect` hook BUT now React will throw a warning about missing dependencies of `useEffect` hook and that is because you will need to add the function `getPackages` in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook BUT this will also lead to infinite execution of the `useEffect` hook.

You have two options to fix this problem:

1. Get rid of `getPackages` function and move its code inside the `useEffect` hook

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
      if(!packages){
        (async () => {
          const resp1 = await instance.get(...);
          setPackages(resp1);
        })(); 
      }
   }, []);
   ```
2. Use the `useCallback` hook to memoize the `getPackages` function so that it can be safely added in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook.

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
        if(!packages){
            getPackages();
        }
    }, [getPackages]);

   const getPackages = useCallback(async () => {
       const resp1 = await instance.get(...);
       setPackages(resp1);
   }, []);
   ```

Also you don't need the folowing check inside the `useEffect` hook:

```
if(!packages) {
   ...
}
```

This check is not only unnecessary but will also lead to problems:

1. Using `packages` inside the `useEffect` will lead to a warning about the missing dependencies of the `useEffect` hook. This can be fixed by adding `packages` in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook
2. If you add `packages` in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook, it can lead to your original problem, i.e. infinite execution of the `useEffect` hook.

   `useEffect` hook shouldn't update the state that is specified in its dependency array.
3. As the initial value of `packages` is an array, `if (!packages)` condition will never be true because an array is a truthy value and inverting it will always evaluate to false.

   You probably meant to write `if (!packages.length)` but as mentioned before, this check is unnecessary.

Here's how I would rewrite your component:

```
function Packages() {

    const [packages, setPackages] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
       instance
          .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
          .then((data) => setPackages(data))
          .catch(error => { /* handle error */ };
    }, []);
}
```

For further reading on `useEffect` hook, read: [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a second argument for the `useEffect`. Check the documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect).

Eg:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(!packages){
        // ... function here
    }
}, [packages]);
```

Comment: @yousaf, I worded that comment poorly. But won't this loop infinitely? `packages` changes, the effect gets the data and updates the state, then the effect is called again, fetches data, updates the state, gets called _again_...?

Comment: @Andy `if (!packages)` check will stop the effect from updating the state again once the state has been populated. So, there will be only 1 extra execution of the `useEffect` hook after the state has been updated. I guess this was the initial intention of the OP but this check is completely unnecessary here.

Comment: `if (!packages.length)` maybe.

Comment: ah, yes. Initial value of `packages` is an array, so `if (!packages)` will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

Add a dependancy array

like this:

```
     useEffect(() => {
            if(!packages){
                getPackages();
            }
        },[packages]);
```